# Openlayers 3 add WKT to ol.feature

Tags: openlayers-3

is there a way to add ol.format.WKT.readFeature to ol.feature 
i try to add multiple features to a single layers but i can't use wkt as the geometry of each feature.

this is my code for now so multiple layer will be created by this code. what i want is just a single layer with multiple features.

```
 for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1 ; i++)
        {
           thisfill = fill;
                thisstroke = stroke;
                var styles = [new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Circle({
                        fill: thisfill,
                        stroke: thisstroke,
                        radius: 5
                    }),
                    fill: thisfill,
                    stroke: thisstroke
                })];

                customBldgLayerDC = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: new ol.source.Vector({
                        features: [feature],
                    }),
                    style: styles,
                });
                map.addLayer(customBldgLayerDC);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

so i already figured out the answer i just need to add the wkt as geometry in feature. this [Link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206924/openlayers-3-plotting-wkt-format-polygons-on-single-layer-from-array) help me understand my problem

**Working Code**

```
for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1 ; i++)
            {
                var thisfill = data[i].FILL;
                var thisstroke = data[i].STROKE;
                console.log(thisfill);
                console.log(thisstroke);
                var thisstyle = [ new ol.style.Style({
                          image: new ol.style.Circle({
                              fill: thisfill,
                              stroke: thisstroke,
                              radius: 5
                          }),
                          fill: thisfill,
                          stroke: thisstroke,
                      })
                ];

                var format = new ol.format.WKT();
                var wkt = data[i].WKT;
                var geom = format.readGeometry(wkt);


                RLfeature = new ol.Feature({
                    type: 'redline',
                    geometry: geom,
                    overlayID: data[i].REDLINEID
                });

                RLfeature.setStyle(thisstyle);
                RLvector.getSource().addFeature(RLfeature);
                console.log(RLfeature);

            }
        }
```